# how to block width expansion of div from right side without using position absolute?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a div element which expands only from left side when we add any content in it.

```
<div 
    id="sent_message"
    style='background-color: #2b89cc; color: white; font-family: Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-top: 10px; display: inline-block; max-width: 50%; min-width: 20%; font-size: 25px; border-radius: 5px; word-wrap: break-word; position: relative; right: -1360;'>
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

I **don't** want to use `position:absolute` for this job. Is there any way to block the expansion of div from theright side? I will be greatful for an answer.

Comment: Are you rejecting position absolute because the element will then have no effect on layout? I was going to suggest positioning left then translating but that also will have a (different) effect on layout (as will float).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `float:right`

```js
window.setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('#sent_message p').innerHTML = 'Hello World, welcome!';
}, 1000);
```

```css
#sent_message {
  background-color: #2b89cc;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 50%;
  min-width: 20%;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="sent_message">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```